# nhibernate, How to create a Custon IUserType for the type "numeric array"

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I have a type numeric[] in my postgresql table, I'm trying to use nhibernate to mapping this with my class

```
    public class Samples {
        public virtual int SampleId { get; set; }
        public virtual double[] Spectro { get; set; }        
        public virtual int ExamId { get; set; } 
        public virtual short Num { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public SamplesMap() {
            Table("samples");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.SampleId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("sample_id");
            Map(x => x.Spectro).Column("spectro");
            Map(x => x.ExamId).Column("exam_id").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Num).Column("num").Not.Nullable();
        }
```

With this I'm getting ( Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 42804: column "spectro" is of type double precision[] but expression is of type bytea )

I know I need make a custom type, but I dont know how. I've seen some exemples of custom types, but nothing like a numeric array.

Please, help me!

Comment: Im not sure is a good source, but is related with your issue https://github.com/daanl/Fluent-NHibernate--PostgreSQL-column-array

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Najera ! only adjustment I did was change string for duble. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The source ([github.com/daanl/Fluent-NHibernate--PostgreSQL-column-array](http://github.com/daanl/Fluent-NHibernate--PostgreSQL-column-array) ) brought to me by Najera was the answer! Just change string by double.

Comment: You may accept your own answer, Stack Overflow welcome this. But please include the relevant part of the link having helped you solve your trouble. Link only answer become useless if the link goes broken.